# should we provide default implementation for the middle inherited classes

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
public:
    A(…) {…}
    virtual ~A() {…}
    
private:
    // may contains data
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(…) {…}
private:
    // contains no data
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    C(…) {…}
    ~C() {…}
private:
    // may contains data
};
```

As you can see, `class A` is the base class so we have to provide a implemented virtual destructor.

Question> Do we have to provide a default destructor for a concrete `class B`?
`class B` itself doesn't require to implement a customized destructor to release any allocated resource.

Thank you

Comment: No. <extra characters to make limit>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Once one base destructor is virtual, all derived destructors are automatically virtual. If the default implementation suffices, you do not need to provide a user-defined destructor.

(In fact, if the default implementation suffices even in the base, you should declare and define it as `virtual ~A() = default;`, rather than with an empty body.)

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to that in case you don't have resources to release.

The same is applied to any other methods including `virtual` and `pure virtual`